# `docker service update` not working to update config

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Firstly every step is done seemingly successfully (not any error reported). But per what I understand about how to check if the new config is applied OK, it seems to be failed updating the config.

Suppose I have a config file with a simple content like this:

```
Well done
```

I created a config (the first version) like this:

```
echo 'Well done' | docker config create my-config -
```

Now I have a local file named `my-config.txt` (on the host machine) with content as described above, it's used as a template (source) to clone over the target on the Docker container. On the Docker container, there is already a config file with the same content (originally). Now I change the content of the file `my-config.txt` (on the host machine) to something like this:

```
Well done !!!
```

And next I update the current docker service (created before) by using `docker service update` to apply the new config file, like this:

```
//firstly create another version of config
docker config create my-config-2 /home/my_user/my-config.txt
docker service update \
   --config-add source=my-config-2,target=my-config.txt \
   --config-rm my-config \
   my-service
```

As I said, it seems to execute successfully. But when I try opening the `my-config.txt` file on the Docker container, its content is kept unchanged, like this:

```
docker exec [container_id] cat my-config.txt
```

It still shows `Well done` whereas the expected content should be `Well done !!!`. Isn't that what it should be? Am I doing something wrong here? Or could you suggest something to diagnose this issue or something different from what I've done without having to trying to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you verify that service restarted? I.e. you have a different <container-id> after calling the `docker service update`.

Comment: What will happen if you put `--config-rm` option first (before `--config-add`)?

Comment: Does `docker service ps <your-service>` show any errors after update?

Comment: @achempion sorry that I don't have access to my laptop now, I'll test it out after today working in office. However I can say that the service was surely restarted, at least if the `update` command succeeds, in some cases it may not restart (and we can use `--force` option) but here actually my host machine was restarted meaning the `docker service` was restarted as well and I checked the config file again, still no change applied. I hope changing the order of `--config-rm` and `--config-add` will work.

Comment: @achempion I've just tried it out, looks like it is still not working. I can see that the config is applied by using `docker service inspect`, it shows the new config name. However the old content is not replaced. `docker service ps` does not show any error, the service is surely restarted (I even tried restarting it manually using `docker service scale`).

Comment: What if you change the `docker config create my-config-2 /home/my_user/my-config.txt` command to `docker config create my-config-2 /home/my_user/my-config-2.txt` as well and apply `--config-add source=my-config-2,target=my-config-2.txt`. Will it at least create a new file with the correct content? Also, try to use completely separate names just to localize steps to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @achempion I've just tried what you suggested, still nothing changed. Actually I think the source file will have its content copied to the created config (so we can use one same file for multiple configs of the same content).

Comment: @achempion sorry for your time trying to solve my problem which is actually simpler than what I (or both of us) could think of. Somehow I've found that the config file was put to the parent folder (that's why the config file in the `app` folder could not be replaced). So instead of this `target=my-config.txt`, I should have had written `target=app/my-config.txt`. So actually my original command should have worked expectedly, just not working due to wrong `target` dir :( Just a painful waste of time for both of us.

Comment: I'm glad you have resolved an issue :)